# How to write a universal "magic length" getter and setter without memory leaks?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
function magicLengthGetter() {
    var last = Math.max.apply(null,
        Object.keys(this)
        .map(Number)
        .filter(function(el) {
            return el >= 0 && el === el;
        })
    );
    if (last === -Infinity) {
        return 0;
    }
    return last + 1;
};

function magicLengthSetter(val) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach(function(el, i, arr) {
        var modified = Number(el);
        if (modified === modified /* NaN check */ && modified >= val) {
            delete this[el];
        }
    }, this);
    return val;
};
function addMagicLengthProperty(what, readOnly) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        readOnly = true;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(what, 'length', {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        get: magicLengthGetter,
        set: readOnly ? Function() : magicLengthSetter
    });
    return what;
};
```

It works good most of times, but it breaks in few cases.
Eg.

```
var wow = addMagicLength({});
wow[3] = 'foo';
wow.length; // 4
wow.length = 0;
wow[3]; // undefined
wow.length = 50;
wow.length; // 0; Should be 50 and be like array with holes
```

How can I fix this issue without using WeakMaps, creating copy of accessors for every instance of class or memory leaks?

Comment: What is `addMagicLength`?

Comment: Function that sets magicLengthGetter as getter of `length` property.

Comment: This is a well-studied problem and is somewhere between not trivial and impossible without some ES6 features which make it possible to truly inherit from `Array` including the behavior of the `length` property. What is your particular use case?

Comment: Have you considered using `Object.observe`?

Comment: How can `Object.observe` solve problems with holes in array-like? O.o